# For $x+y=n$, $y^x < x^y$ if $x<y$.

Tags: inequality

(*updated*)
I'd like to use this property for my research, but it's somewhat messy to prove.

$$\text{For all natural number $x,y$ such that $x+y=n$ and $1<x<y<n$, then $y^x < x^y$}.$$

For example, let $x=3, y=7$. Then $y^x = y^3 = 343$ and $x^y = 3^7 = 2187$. Any suggestion on how to prove this?

Comment: Is $n$ a positive integer? Is there any bound on $n$? This is not true though. $n=6=2+4$ and $2^4 = 4^2$.

Comment: Well that is not really true now is it... $(-4)^2>2^{-4}$ for example.  An even better example is $3^2>2^3$... Having said that, if both $x,y>e=2.7818\dots$, then we always have the implication $x<y\Rightarrow y^x<x^y$.

Comment: @Fed: The counterexample I gave still works for(or rather, against) your update.

Comment: $x=2,y=3,n=5$ still stands as a counter example.

Comment: It is true if $x$ and $y$ are integers and $n \gt 6$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lets ask the general question

> When does $x<y\Rightarrow y^x<x^y$ hold for real $x,y$?

Taking logarithms, we are asking when $x<y$ implies $x\log y<y\log x$, or when $$\frac{x}{\log x}<\frac{y}{\log y}.$$  Notice this is the same as when the function $f(x)=\frac{x}{\log x}$ is increasing.  To answer that we look at the derivative, and since

$$f^{'}(x)=\frac{\log(x)-1}{\log^2(x)}$$

we see the derivative is only positive, and that the function is only increasing, when $x>e$.  Hence if $x,y>e$ you will have $$x<y\Rightarrow y^x<x^y.$$

If $0<x,y<e$ and $x,y\neq 1$, then the derivative is actually negative, and we get the opposite $$ 1<x<y<e,\ x,y\neq 1\ \Rightarrow y^x>x^y.$$

Answer (score 5):

The claim is false. $1^{10}<10^1$. Even if you exclude the $x=1$ case, $2^3<3^2$.

Answer (score 5):

I proved this in the special case $x = 99, y = 100$, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103431/which-of-the-numbers-99100-and-10099-is-the-larger-one/103434#103434).  As others have pointed out, what you really want to hold is the following:

**Statement:** Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.  Then $y > x > e$ implies $x^y > y^x$.

*Proof:*.  Write $y = x + z$, where $z > 0$.  Then,

$$\begin{align}
x^y > y^x &\iff  x^x x^z > y^x
\\
&\iff x^z > \left(\frac{x+z}{x} \right)^x
\\
&\iff x^z > \left( 1 + \frac{z}{x} \right)^x.
\end{align}$$

The right hand side $\left(1 + \frac{z}{x} \right)^x$ is monotone increasing with limit $e^z$.  Since the left hand size is strictly greater than $e^z$ (as $x > e$), it follows that the inequality always holds.