# How can I prove that $x^k = O(k^x)$?

Tags: asymptotics

Suppose that k is a constant.

I figured out that $k^x \geq x^k$ is true for $x \geq k$. But I couldn't find a way to prove it.

Comment: FYI, a very similar question re: trying to prove that "$k^x \geq x^k$ is true for $x \geq k$" is at [For $x+y=n$, $y^x < x^y$ if $x<y$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/112900/602049).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prove that you can find some $C > 0$ such that

$$ x^k \leq C k^x $$

Notice that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{ k^x }{x^k } = \infty$ by Lhopitals (  k times) rule and so we can find some $C$ such that $\dfrac{k^x}{x^k} > C $ and thus $Cx^k < k^x $ which means that $x^k = O( k^x ) $

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^k}{k^x} = \frac{\infty}{\infty}
\end{align}
Now, take the derivative of numerator and denominator to obtain
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{k x^{k-1}}{k^x \log(k)} $$
Repeating the steps above $k$ times (L'Hopital rule) we conclude that the limit equals 0.  This means that $k^x$ grows faster than $x^k$.  Hence, $x^k \in O(k^x)$.